# Why is copying memory on EC2 machines slow?

Tags: python, memory, amazon-ec2

Memory copies seem to be surprisingly slow on my EC2 machine.  I'd like to track down why.

On most computers I observe bulk memory copy bandwidths of 3000 MB/s.  See the following Python snippet:

```
In [1]: data = b'0' * int(1e8)  # 100 MB

In [2]: %time len(data[1:])     # memcopy
CPU times: user 18.4 ms, sys: 8.62 ms, total: 27.1 ms
Wall time: 27.1 ms
Out[2]: 99999999

In [3]: 100000000 / 0.027 / 1e6  # MB/s
Out[3]: 3703.703703703704
```

However, on EC2, this changes significantly

```
In [1]: data = b'0' * int(1e8)  # 100 MB

In [2]: %time len(data[1:])     # memcopy
CPU times: user 44 ms, sys: 148 ms, total: 192 ms
Wall time: 192 ms
Out[2]: 99999999

In [3]: 100000000 / 0.192 / 1e6  # MB/s
Out[3]: 520.8333333333333
```

I have *never* seen memcpy run that slowly before.  What is the likely cause?

### Setup

Software environments are mostly the same.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Anaconda with Python 2.7 on each machine.  Hardware *is* different

- Laptop (Thinkpad w540): Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
- EC2 Machine (m4.xlarge): Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz

Comment: You are comparing a physical server to a virtual machine. Try loading up VirtualBox on your Laptop and running your test inside that for a better comparison.

Comment: Are you using iPython?
On a i5-2500 it takes about 45 msec, while on a t2.micro AWS instance it takes about 33 msec when using pure python3 code.

Comment: @MarkB I did that and I don't observe nearly as much slowdown on my virtual machine.  It ranges somewhere between 0 and 70% slower.